# How to send a XML formatted POST request with RestKit 0.20.1

Tags: ios, xml, http-post, restkit-0.20

I have an iOS app that is using RestKit 0.20.1 to pull data from a server.  The server at this time can send JSON formatted data but is not able to receive JSON formatted data.

This is where my problem is. POST requests require HTTP Body and the server is set up to receive XML.  I have implemented the RKXMLReaderSerialization add on so I can receive XML but I can't find any current way of sending an XML formatted HTTP Body with RestKit.

This question "[Send post request in XML format using RestKit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8882472/send-post-request-in-xml-format-using-restkit) " is what I was looking for but the answer from Imran Raheem is now (as far as I can tell) obsolete  due to changes in RestKit.

I am using this method for the POST

```
[[RKObjectManager sharedManager] postObject:nil path:@"/rest/search?ip=255.255.255.0" parameters:search success:nil failure:nil];
```

Here is what the RestKit objectManager says about the postObject method

```
/**
 Creates an `RKObjectRequestOperation` with a `POST` request for the given object, and enqueues it to the manager's operation queue.
     @param object The object with which to construct the object request operation. If `nil`, then the path must be provided.
     @param path The path to be appended to the HTTP client's base URL and used as the request URL. If nil, the request URL will be obtained by consulting the router for a route registered for the given object's class and the `RKRequestMethodPOST` method.
     @param parameters The parameters to be reverse merged with the parameterization of the given object and set as the request body.
     @param success A block object to be executed when the object request operation finishes successfully. This block has no return value and takes two arguments: the created object request operation and the `RKMappingResult` object created by object mapping the response data of request.
     @param failure A block object to be executed when the request operation finishes unsuccessfully, or that finishes successfully, but encountered an error while parsing the resonse data. This block has no return value and takes two arguments:, the created request operation and the `NSError` object describing the network or parsing error that occurred.
```

If I have the `MIMEType` set to JSON the Trace shows my `request.body` is being populated like so `request.body={"Search":"Trending"}`.

However if I set the `MIMEType` to XML the Trace shows the `request.body=(null)`

Here is the line I use to change the `MIMEType`

```
[RKObjectManager sharedManager].requestSerializationMIMEType = RKMIMETypeJSON;
```

I am pretty new to iOS and Objective-C so I may be setting up the NSDictionary that is used in the parameters of the `postObject' method wrong.  Here it is just in case....

```
NSArray *objects =[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"trending", nil];
NSArray *keys =[NSArray arrayWithObjects: @"Search",nil];
NSDictionary *params = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjects:objects forKeys:keys];
self.search=params;
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!  Given that I am new Snippets are especially helpful!

Oh and BTW if anyone can point me to REST method that accepts JSON input I would gladly pass it on to my server guy so I can just avoid XML all together.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As feared and suggested in other posts on this topic writing XML is not supported in version of RestKit 0.20.1.  Here is a link to my conversation with Blake Watters on the subject.

https://github.com/RestKit/RestKit/issues/1430#issuecomment-19150316

I never did clear up why the request.body= (null) when the MIMEType is set to XML.

The manager of the server has agreed to set it up to receive JSON.  That is how I plan to work around this.